# How to put spaces betwwen buttons horizontally using css?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image]When buttons shift to second line, they are attached to eachother and not looking good, i want to put space between buttons horizontally.

```html
      <div class="container">
    <div class="tim-title">
        <h3>What intrests you?</h3>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-round" placement="right"
        ngbPopover="Here will be some very useful information about this popover." popoverTitle="Popover on right">
        Artificial Intelligence
    </button>
    &nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-round" placement="top"
        ngbPopover="Here will be some very useful information about this popover." popoverTitle="Popover on top">
        Management
    </button>
    &nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-round" placement="left"
        ngbPopover="Here will be some very useful information about this popover." popoverTitle="Popover on left">
        Data Science
    </button>
    &nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-round" placement="bottom"
        ngbPopover="Here will be some very useful information about this popover." popoverTitle="Popover on bottom">
        FInance
    </button>
    &nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-round" placement="right"
    ngbPopover="Here will be some very useful information about this popover." 
    popoverTitle="Popover on right">
    Human Resource
    </button>
    &nbsp;
    

      </div>
```

Comment: bootstrap 4.....

Comment: Could you clarify if you want spaces vertically or horizontally? The wording in your question is a little confusing for me.

Comment: button1 button2 button3.................................................second line.space button4

Comment: You could add the `mb-3` class to every button

Comment: @DCR since this is a Bootstrap question and the CSS is relevant, when you edit it, it makes sense to include the CDN link to Bootstrap

Comment: ye include the link to bootstrap so the styling works

Comment: using bootstrap 4 with angular

Comment: I have edited the question, iT Is currently showing like this, as you can see there is no spacing between two lines

Comment: second line buttons are attached to first line, that is not looking good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To each button add mb-3 class (as stated in previous comments) and I would also add mr-3 class (or mr-2) **instead** of the `&nbsp;` (it's just nicer practice and usage of bootstrap).

like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tim-title">
        <h3>What intrests you?</h3>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-round mb-3 mr-3" placement="right" ngbPopover="Here will be some very useful information about this popover." popoverTitle="Popover on right">
        Artificial Intelligence
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-round mb-3 mr-3" placement="top" ngbPopover="Here will be some very useful information about this popover." popoverTitle="Popover on top">
        Management
    </button>
    
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to simply put a `<br>` element between the buttons.

Another solution would be to put a horizontal margin between buttons. If you are using Bootstrap, the class `my-3` might be useful to achieve this.

For more info about margin on Bootstrap, here is the official guide: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/

Comment: I have edited the question, iT Is currently showing like this, as you can see there is no spacing between two lines.

Answer (score 0):

just add padding using

```
style=padding-left:3%
```

put this inside the button you want to move left

EDIT:

you are using bootstrap so add m-3 to every button to every button on the page so they are spaced out on all sides.

Comment: i dont want to move button to left , I just to put space when buttons shift to second line, I want to put space bwteen 1st line button and 2nd line button

Comment: Oh then just add margin to all of the button on the page using class=m-3 in your tag. If you only want it on the bottom add mb-3 to the buttons on the top row

Comment: I have edited the question, iT Is currently showing like this, as you can see there is no spacing between two lines

Comment: Add a div around the top row of button then give that a class of mb-3 should probably help

Answer (score 0):

ok so if this is the first row of buttons then do this:

```
<div class="mb-3"> <!-- NEW DIV HERE -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-round" placement="right"
        ngbPopover="Here will be some very useful information about this popover." popoverTitle="Popover on right">
        Artificial Intelligence
    </button>
    &nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-round" placement="top"
        ngbPopover="Here will be some very useful information about this popover." popoverTitle="Popover on top">
        Management
    </button>
    &nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-round" placement="left"
        ngbPopover="Here will be some very useful information about this popover." popoverTitle="Popover on left">
        Data Science
    </button>
    &nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-round" placement="bottom"
        ngbPopover="Here will be some very useful information about this popover." popoverTitle="Popover on bottom">
        FInance
    </button>
    &nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-round" placement="right"
    ngbPopover="Here will be some very useful information about this popover." 
    popoverTitle="Popover on right">
    Human Resource
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-round" placement="right"
    ngbPopover="Here will be some very useful information about this popover." 
    popoverTitle="Popover on right">
    Ennginering
    </button>
</div> <!-- END DIV HERE -->

<!-- NEXT ROW OF BUTTONS -->
```

Comment: If mb-3 is not large enough gap then use mb-4 or mb-5